# problema al inicializar objeto

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

hola buenas intento inicializar un objeto que internamente tiene dos listas básicamente la orden seria

El objeto facturación adentro tiene un objeto de tipo cliente, y el objeto de tipo cliente tiene adentro dos listas una de tipo tours y otra lista de tipo producto. ejeje les muestro las clases

```
public class Facturacion
{
    public Cliente cliente { get; set; }

}
```

Luego tenemos la clase clientes que va haci

```
public class Cliente
{

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "La Cedula es Obligatoria")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[1-9]-\d{4}-\d{4}$", ErrorMessage = "La Cedula debe Digitarse en el formato [#-####-####] y debe contener 9 caracteres")]
    public string Cedula { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Nombre Completo")]
    [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 10, ErrorMessage = "El Nombre es Obligatorio")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "El Nombre es Obligatorio")]
    public string? NombreCompleto { get; set; }
   public List<listasFacturacion> facturacion { get; set; }
```

}

luego las listasFacturacion

```
public class listasFacturacion
{
    public List<Tours> tour { get; set; }

    public  List<Producto> producto { get; set; }

}
```

y aquí intento crear todo el objeto conjunto, pero por se tanta cosa jajaj nose como quedaría

```
        var clientefacturar = Almacenamiento.clientes.Find(o => o.Cedula == nuevaFacturacion.idCliente);

        var productoFacturar = Almacenamiento.productos.Find(o => o.Id_ == nuevaFacturacion.idProducto);
        //listasFacturar.producto.Add(productoFacturar);

        var toursFacturar = Almacenamiento.tours.Find(o => o.Id == nuevaFacturacion.idTours);
        //listasFacturar.tour.Add(toursFacturar);
```

//aquí está el problema. tengo que crear un objeto facturación, y de allí meterme a cliente y luego al siguiente objeto y de alli a las listas pero nose como quedaria el objeto.

```
        Facturacion itemFacturar = new Facturacion
        {
           cliente { new List<Tours>{  Tours = toursFacturar } }

        };
```

estas son mis listas de almacenamiento

```
    public static List<Producto> productos = new List<Producto>
    {
       new Producto
       {
           Id_ = 0,
           Descripcion = "Camisa de león",
           Año = 2020,
           precio = 12000,
           Utilidad = 5,
           provedor = new Provedor{Cedula = "6-3223-2345", Descripcion = "Provedor mas confiable"}
       }
    };

    public static List<Provedor> proveedores = new List<Provedor> 
    {
        new Provedor
        {
            Cedula = "6-3223-2345",
            Descripcion = "Provedor mas confiable"
        }
    };
```

sera que me puedan ayudar.

Comment: EL código como texto. La última imagen puedes dejarla (pero también debes agregar esa info como texto). Piensa que yo pare reproducir tu error tengo que ir viendo la imagen y escribiendo, pero para ti (que eres el interesado en recibir la ayuda) es solo copiar y pegar

Comment: a ok perdon voy a editar la pregunta

Comment: si y gracias si me ayudas, como notas para pasarle los objetos a las listas de tours y producto tengo que entrar en varios objetos antes, entonces no me sale el codigo

Comment: Estas usando entity framework o son solo listas ????

Comment: son solo listas normales

Comment: nada de entity framework

Comment: Facturacion itemFacturar = new Facturacion()
        {
           cliente = Almacenamiento.clientes.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Cedula == nuevaFacturacion.idCliente)

        };

Comment: Es esto de arriba lo que quieres?

Comment: aja si eso me sirve pero y luego para entrar desde cliente al siguiente objeto y meter las dos listas siguientes ?

Comment: ok el cliente alli esta ok, pero si notas  cliente luego tiene  public List<listasFacturacion> facturacion { get; set; } entonces como entraria a este siguiente objeto, para ingresar la lista de productos y tours ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que hacer algo como esto:

```
var c = Almacenamiento.clientes.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Cedula == nuevaFacturacion.idCliente);

c.producto= Almacenamiento.productos.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id_ == nuevaFacturacion.idProducto);
     
c.tour= Almacenamiento.tours.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id == nuevaFacturacion.idTours);
      
Facturacion itemFacturar = new Facturacion() 
{ 
   cliente =c
};
```

Comment: waw jajajajajj eso se podia jajaajj

Comment: que poder jejeje ok muchas gracias